# sending the length of the buffer and receive it with C from python

Tags: python, c, struct

I am using this simple python server code to send the length of the buffer
that I am about to send:

```
def server_mode(ip, port):    
    try:    
        s = socket()    
        s.bind((ip, port))    
        print ("[*] Listening on %s:%d\n[*] Waiting for clients" % (ip, port))    
        if ("win32" == os.sys.platform):    
            print("[*] Press Ctrl + Break to stop server")
            elif ("linux" in os.sys.platform):
                print("[*] Press Ctrl + C to stop server")
            while True:
                s.listen(MAX_CLIENTS)
                client, client_ip = s.accept()
                client_ip = client_ip[0]
                print("[*] Got connection from %s" % client_ip)
                buf = struct.pack(">I", 7313)
                client.send(buf)
                client.close()
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            s.close()
            print("[*] Closed socket")
            exit()
        except:
            s.close()
            raise
```

then using this C code the client should receive the length of the buffer that
I am about to send and malloc the needed place for the buffer and receive it:

```
    char* buf = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    recv(sockfd, buf, 4, 0);
    int buf_len = *buf;
```

and it works but only convert the two first bytes of the 4 bytes long int,
For example if I use it to send the `len` of buffer in the size of 13, It receive it fine, but on a number like 7313 it receives 54.

Comment: It's very hard to write ugly code in python, you just did it, congratulations.

Comment: @iharob : I think Stackoverflow needs some assistant that detects common problems "It seems like you're trying to format code by inserting a blank line after every line. Can I move your cursor to the "format as source code" button". Maybe in the form of a paperclip avatar?

Comment: @MarcusMüllerꕺꕺ Anything that prevents hurting our eyes. You can suggest that on stack overflow meta.

Comment: @iharob: I will **not** seriously suggest [Clippy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Assistant) on meta -- you know, that's my real name and I want to feel safe online.

Comment: Why not send the size as an ASCII text string?  It would be much simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
int buf_len = *buf;
```

will not magically read `sizeof buf_len` (you seem to expect it to be four) bytes from `buf`, since `*buf` is a value of type `char`.

You should use `uint8_t` rather than `char`, and `uint32_t` rather than `int`, and read as many as you need, respecting endianness of course:

```
uint8_t buf[4];
if(recv(sockfd, buf, sizeof buf, 0) == 4)
{
  const uint32_t buf_len = ((uint32_t) buf[0] << 24) |
                           ((uint32_t) buf[1] << 16) |
                           ((uint32_t) buf[2] << 8) |
                           buf[3];
  ...
}
```

Comment: I expect it to be four since I used struct.pack in the python server code, which pack the value to the four bytes of an int

Comment: @user3609537 I understand that you expect four bytes on the wire, but that doesn't make `int` four bytes in C, which is what you seemed to expect to happen somehow.

Comment: so if I replace int with uint32_t it should fix this ? because it's not

Comment: @cdarke The other end is Python. He uses big-endian packing explicitly in the Python code, that's why I used big-endian.

Comment: @user3609537 Did you not read my entire answer, above? I did post more code than just a single change from `int` to `uint32_t`. That code is not there for fun, you know. :)

Comment: @user3609537 Great. Feel free to accept the answer.